# What effect would "simultaneous combat" have on Fate gameplay?

Tags: fate, house-rules, conflicts

By default, there is an element of retaliation in defending [*with style*](http://fate-srd.com/fate-core/four-outcomes#succeed-with-style), where you gain a boost, but what about using simultaneous combat rules instead? In simultaneous combat, attackers take damage on an unsuccessful attack proportionate to the success of the defender.

> John, a player, rolls **+5** when trying to attack an enemy.
>   Said enemy rolls **+6** for its defense. It **retaliates**, dealing **1** stress to John.

What effect does this have on the way the game runs?

Comment: Answerers: keep in mind that evaluating a house rule should be done from playtest experience with the house rule, not theory guesses.

Answer (score 7):

It would have to make sense in the narrative, which it might not. A lot of combat behaviours don't have clear retaliations:

- Making a ranged attack against someone without a ranged weapon
- Kicking someone while they are down
- Attacking someone who doesn't want to fight back / is only defending
- Fighting with a large group of people
- Using Provoke who doesn't know you well enough to emotionally hurt you

As such, it would require a lot of GM intervention to constantly describe how this happens *or* a lot of exceptions to the rule in general.

If you want to handle it mechanically, it's better to use a Stunt for it. I think there is one in the Fate SRD as an example, but I cannot find it. But I think it went something like

> When you Defend with Style in melee combat, you may choose to inflict a 2-stress hit instead of receiving a Boost.

That ties it to the character and rules out most situations where it doesn't make sense, without requiring modifications to the main rules.

Answer (score -1):

I think it would be a great idea to play this way.
The problem is: how do you handle something else than duels?

When you only have 2 opponents, that's easy. But when 3+ characters are fighting together, you have to figure a way to cope with initiative, which is easier to deal with when combat is asymmetric.

You'd have to do away with Conflict rules I believe, which work only upon an asymmetric-combat assumption, and adopt an ad-hoc resolution (i.e "He does that, what do you?", "I respond with that", and figure out which skills to roll) everytime a fight happens.